# Run a script with a different user credentials implemented

Tags: windows, permissions, script, file-permissions, vbscript

I have a VBS script that create folders and subfolders.

```
dim filesys, newfolder, newfolderpath, number, address
number=inputbox("Please enter the request number to create","Request number")
address=inputbox("Please enter the damage address","Damage address")
'update the folder path in the below line
newfolderpath="\\cads01\new projects\2020\"
newfolderpath = newfolderpath +number +" - " +address
set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not filesys.FolderExists(newfolderpath) Then
Set newfolder = filesys.CreateFolder(newfolderpath)
Set newfolder = filesys.CreateFolder(newfolderpath+ "\Photos")
Set newfolder = filesys.CreateFolder(newfolderpath+ "\Factures")
Set newfolder = filesys.CreateFolder(newfolderpath+ "\PO's - Devis")
Set newfolder = filesys.CreateFolder(newfolderpath+ "\Correspondance")
Set newfolder = filesys.CreateFolder(newfolderpath+ "\Documents Facturation")
msgbox "Folders are created!"
End If
```

It will be run by users. I have set permissions for users so they can't create folders or to drop any files out of the folders created by the script.

The problem is that when they run the script, the creation of the folders is "permission denied".
I would like that the script can be run as another user that has the permissions to create folders, and without entering any credentials.
Basically, that the script will run as a user with privileges.

Comment: If users can run that script without entering credentials, you might as well give them privileges to create folders.

Comment: You want allow the users to create folders but with an execution of a script that runs without credential though that the user can run. What's wrong with just allowing the users to create the folders, you will let them do this with a script click and no credential so I don't see what value you add to the process doing it with the script elevated with no credential information needed?

Comment: Otherwise, delegate the creation of top folders to managers or have them come to you or someone else that has permission and can approve that the folder creation request is appropriate and create it then per request. If not, just allow them to do it without additional script, etc.

Comment: @Berend.
The point is that I don't want them to create any other folders than the ones specified in that script. I want to keep the same structure for all our jobs, and nobody listens, so I had to put such a thing in place.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT,
The point is that I don't want them to create any other folders than the ones specified in that script. I want to keep the same structure for all our jobs, and nobody listens, so I had to put such a thing in place.

Comment: Then this looks like an X/Y question. The real question would be more like 'how can I allow users to create only folders with a certain name'. Now that makes sense. One option would be to build a website that creates the subfolders. The website could run with certain privileges. You could also write a service application, or a scheduled task, that monitors the base folder and creates subfolders if a new folder is detected.

Comment: Then why not just create the static folders to begin with rather than adding static folder names to a script for them to run. Once a folder is created, does it get deleted so that it must be added back later or something like that? Who is adding new folder names to the script when there are new or different folders that are needed? If you have a standard, why not just define it, and force them to request or have someone approve a new folder creation to go to the person to create it and set the security, etc. I still don't see the point in maintaining a script now that someone must change.

Comment: Someone is doing something and making a conscience decision at script modify time or at folder creation time. Seems the script adds overhead in this case unless the vb logic is also setting the security post folder creation eliminating that manual part. Otherwise, the person modifying the script can just run it or create the folder manually. This adds unnecessary overhead otherwise thinking of it from a logical perspective so I still don't see the benefit, its just adding a complexity that's not needed.

Comment: Could you create a scheduled task to run your script, as a way of getting it to run as an account with permissions, e.g. System.  You can choose to run it on a certain event ID being created in say the application event log.  The script the user then runs, doesn't create the folders but creates the event log entry to fire the script to create the folders.  Of course, don't put the script in a location the users can modify it otherwise they could run any command as the account you schedule the task as. Could offer something.